# Get the name of Instagram profile and the date of post with Python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, instagram

I'm in the process of learning `python3` and I try to solve a simple task. I want to get the *name of account* and the *date of post* from instagram link.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/BuPSnoTlvTR')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
item = soup.select_one("meta[property='og:description']")
name = item.find_previous_sibling().get("content").split("•")[0]
print(name)
```

This code works sometimes with links like this [https://www.instagram.com/*kingtop*](https://www.instagram.com/_kingtop_)
But I need it to work also with post of image like this https://www.instagram.com/p/BuxB00KFI-x/

That's all what I could make, but this is not working. And I can't get the date also.
Do you have any ideas? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Heya, what would you wanna get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get the name of account. Now I'm trying to find a way to get an  upload date

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

start = time.time()

file = open('users.txt', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
urls = file.readlines()
for url in urls:
url = url.strip ('\n')
try:
    req = requests.get(url)
    req.raise_for_status()
except HTTPError as http_err:
    output = open('output2.txt', 'a')
    output.write(f'не найдена\n')  
except Exception as err:
    output = open('output2.txt', 'a')
    output.write(f'не найдены\n')  
else:
    output = open('output2.txt', 'a')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
    the_url = soup.select("[rel='canonical']")[0]['href']
    the_url2=the_url.replace('https://www.instagram.com/','')
    head, sep, tail = the_url2.partition('/')
    output.write (head+'\n')
```